# How to Create an instance of a polyline in heremaps in javascript?

Tags: javascript, here-api, heredoc, here-maps-rest

So i was creating a polyline to use it in another place but after creating the instance the polyline is getting al mixed up its may be due to linestring or what?

````
var points = [
      { lat: 52.5309825, lng: 13.3845921 },
      { lat: 52.5311923, lng: 13.3853495 }];

var linestring = new H.geo.LineString();
points.forEach(function(point) {
  linestring.pushPoint(point);
});

// Initialize a polyline with the linestring:
var routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring);```

[![if i give multiple polyline inputs the previous one is geting attached][1]][1]

Image of mixed output polylines:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPrHq.png
````

Comment: What exactly is getting mixed up?
I tried your code and map rendered correct polyline: https://prnt.sc/qc0r2m

Comment: i tried to create an instance of polyline and used the instance in another place but linestring is not taking new instance

Comment: Can you share also the code how you use the instance of polyline in another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [setGeometry](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.Polyline.html#setGeometry) method on `H.map.Polyline` object. Here is a sample code which creates Polyline with one LineString and then updates Polyline's geometry with second LineString after 2 seconds:

```js
var points1 = [
      { lat: 52.5309825, lng: 13.3845921 },
      { lat: 52.5311923, lng: 13.3853495 }];
var points2 = [
      { lat:52.532015,lng:13.385634 },
      { lat:52.531441,lng:13.386225 }];
var linestring1 = new H.geo.LineString();
var linestring2 = new H.geo.LineString();

points1.forEach(function(point) {
  linestring1.pushPoint(point);
});

var routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring1);

// update polyline's geometry 
setTimeout(function() {
  routeLine.setGeometry(linestring2);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i have created a lineString instance and a polyline instance.when i want to overwrite this polyline i have used another new lineString instance with the previous polyline instance. this made to get new routing every time i enter two different places

Comment: I think this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: That solved my issue that's why i kept it as an answer should i make it a comment??!!

Comment: Sorry, somehow it didn't look to me as an answer as it didn't have any code snippet. Anyway it's strange to answer your own question within an hour..

Comment: got it with the help on slack! BTW thanks for the response @Tomas